# Resize window to half screen width in KDE 3.5

Tags: rhel, kde, window-manager

I am using a legacy version of Red Hat that uses KDE 3.5.4. I do not have the ability to install additional software. I have become rather addicted to the modern windowing feature of snapping to half-screen; it utilizes widescreen monitor resources well. Is there a way I can achieve this in KDE 3 other than manually dragging them to fit half-screen every time?

(I have already figured out how to make the windows fill the screen only vertically.)

Related...

- ...but [for Gnome](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17824/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-make-a-window-occupy-half-the-screen)
- ...but [for Kubuntu 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119774/resize-window-to-half-width)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KDE 3 does not have the snap-to-halfscreen feature. If you cannot install other software, then you will not have access the the feature.

However, your life can be made easier by middle- and right- clicking on the maximise button of the window chrome. Middle-click will maximise vertically, and right-click will maximise horizontally. You then only need resize one dimension, not two.

Answer (score 2):

**Not in 3.5**, this answer is just for reference.

[in KDE 4.4, drag windows to the screen edge.](https://superuser.com/a/416802/264276)

[You can also assign keyboard shortcuts](https://superuser.com/a/394659/264276):

`System Settings -> Shortcuts and Gestures -> Global Keyboard Shortcuts`

[image]